# flume Command [tail -F] exited with 1

Tags: flume, flume-ng

Trying to run the following command in Linux:

```
bin/flume-ng agent -n a1 -c conf -f conf/flume-tail.properties -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
```

However, the processing stops at:

```
2016-06-26 09:03:44,610 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents(Application.java:138)] Starting new configuration:{ sourceRunners:{r1=EventDrivenSourceRunner: { source:org.apache.flume.source.ExecSource{name:r1,state:IDLE} }} sinkRunners:{k1=SinkRunner: { policy:org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor@3244eabe counterGroup:{ name:null counters:{} } }} channels:{c1=org.apache.flume.channel.MemoryChannel{name: c1}} }
2016-06-26 09:03:44,676 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents(Application.java:145)] Starting Channel c1
2016-06-26 09:03:44,744 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.register(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:120)] Monitored counter group for type: CHANNEL, name: c1: Successfully registered new MBean.
2016-06-26 09:03:44,746 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.start(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:96)] Component type: CHANNEL, name: c1 started
2016-06-26 09:03:44,747 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents(Application.java:173)] Starting Sink k1
2016-06-26 09:03:44,747 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents(Application.java:184)] Starting Source r1
2016-06-26 09:03:44,748 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-3) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.ExecSource.start(ExecSource.java:169)] Exec source starting with command:tail -F
2016-06-26 09:03:44,766 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-3) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.register(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:120)] Monitored counter group for type: SOURCE, name: r1: Successfully registered new MBean.
2016-06-26 09:03:44,766 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-3) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.start(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:96)] Component type: SOURCE, name: r1 started
2016-06-26 09:03:44,785 (pool-3-thread-1) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.ExecSource$ExecRunnable.run(ExecSource.java:376)] Command [tail -F] exited with 1
```

Could anyone help me address this issue?

Comment: Can you show the content of your configuration file?

Answer (score -1):

Check whether the user has the permissions to run `tail -f` on your target dir.

Comment: And what might those permissions be, exactly?